# instanceof with ember-data models not working as expected

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, instanceof

I'm getting some unexpected behaviour from ember-data with instanceof

```
A = DS.Model.extend();
B = A.extend();

store.createRecord('b') instanceof store.modelFor('a') // false ???

X = Ember.Object.extend();
Y = X.extend();

y = Y.create();
y instanceof X // true - works as expected
```

I'm using the latest canary builds of both ember and ember-data. Anyone else come across this?

EDIT: I'm also using ember-cli with the es6 module transpiler. Not sure how/if that could affect anything.

EDIT: Just re-created this using an otherwise empty ember-cli project (http://iamstef.net/ember-cli/#getting-started). I guess I'll file an issue on that project.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/816

Comment: Do you have any resoultion for this? I am also using Ember-cli and have this error.

Comment: @Marecky You can try setting `Ember.MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS` to `false` in your app.js

Comment: Thank you @sheldonnbbaker, this info is what I got from Stefan Penner's post that You already know :) https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/816#issuecomment-44157743 Currently I'm reading what MODEL_FACTORY_INJECTIONS does to Ember

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it's working to me, Are you sure that the store is actually returning the type from `store.modelFor('...')`

Models

```
App.A = DS.Model.extend();
App.B = App.A.extend();
```

Test

```
var aType = store.modelFor('a');
var bRec = store.createRecord('b');
console.log(bRec instanceof aType);
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/512/edit

Comment: Yup - `modelFor` is returning the class as I'm expecting. I just made a jsbin myself and all is working, so perhaps it's something with ember-cli?

Comment: Yeah, sounds like something funky with how it's exported in ember-cli.  You might look into the proto or watch the createRecord process to follow the difference.